# Program is showing error despite following instructions: name 'x_train' is not defined

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The `train_test_split` is showing error.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_df = pd.read_csv(r'fashion-mnist_train.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv(r'fashion-mnist_test.csv')

train_data = np.array(train_df, dtype='float32')
test_data = np.array(test_df, dtype='float32')

x_train = train_data[:, 1:] / 255
y_train = train_data[:, 0]

x_test = test_data[:, 1:] / 255
y_test = test_data[:, 0]

x_train, x_validate, y_train, y_validate = train_test_split(
    x_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=12345,
)
```

when i run the cell with train test split the following error occurs:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-4aa4c00efc7f> in <module>
      2 
      3 x_train, x_validate, y_train, y_validate = train_test_split(
----> 4     x_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=12345,
      5 )
NameError: name 'x_train' is not defined
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: In the NameError message, the parameters passed to train_test_split don't match exactly the code: There is a value 5 passed after the parameter random_state.

Answer (score 0):

There is the problem in dataset csv file naming convention in below code:

```
train_df = pd.read_csv(r'fashion-mnist_train.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv(r'fashion-mnist_test.csv')
```

You need change to it to underscore( _ ) from hyphen ( - ) as below:

```
train_df = pd.read_csv(r'fashion_mnist_train.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv(r'fashion_mnist_test.csv')
```

Also, make the same changes on these file names in your local directory from you are importing these files.